# Import Csv File for product and for product gallery image

Tags: magento-1.8, import, products

I need to import the product using csv file and also need to import the images for product gallery.

Comment: Please be a little more specific here. When asking questions, it is best to outline what you have tried, the trouble you ran into. Stating only what you need really just doesn't give a good starting point for folks to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the fastest way to import products is Magmi.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page

The image attributes processor can let you import gallery images using simple syntax:

```
<image1 location>[::image1 label];<image2 location>[::image2 label]
```

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

---

I don't believe the magento export includes gallery images, but I use this script to export all images to a csv file ready for magmi image attributes processor keeping the images remotely.

```
<?php 
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app(); 
$time_start = microtime(true); 

$pagesize = 3000; //How Many Product Does the Site Have.     

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setPageSize($pagesize)
            //->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => 'b%'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter("visibility", array("eq" => 4))
            ->setOrder('sku', 'asc'); 

$count = $products->count();

// open the csv and write the header in the first row
$fp = fopen('productimages.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku","image","small_image","thumbnail","image_label ","small_image_label ","thumbnail_label ","media_gallery " /* ,"Image" */); 
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader, $delimiter = ",");

    // iterate through all the products
    foreach($products as $_product){

    // load a product object using its sku
        $sku = $_product->getData("sku");
        $product = $_product->load($sku);

        if($product)
            {
            //  $image = 'http://www.yoururl.com/media/catalog/product'.$product->getImage();

                $galleryimages = array();
                foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
                            $galleryimages[] = "http://yoururl.com".$image->getFile();
                        } ;

    $images = implode(";", $galleryimages); // Add them to the list 


    $mediagallery = 

                    $product_row = array($product->getSku(),
                        "http://yoururl.com".$product->getImage(),
                        "http://yoururl.com".$product->getSmall(),
                        "http://yoururl.com".$product->getThumbnail(),
                        $product->getName(),
                        $product->getName(),
                        $product->getName(),
                        $images
                    );

                fputcsv( $fp, $product_row, $delimiter = ",");
            }
     }
//how long?
$time_end = microtime(true);
//dividing with 60 will give the execution time in minutes other wise seconds
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;
```